# Looper: Origin of "Rainmaker" name

Tags: looper

In the film "Looper", young Cid becomes the "Rainmaker" after watching his mother's death at the hands of a looper.

But the origin of the name "Rainmaker" is never explained in the film - it seems like an odd name for someone who takes over six syndicates and almost shuts down all loopers.

Does the name Rainmaker have anything to do with [any of these definitions](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rainmaker) I found in FreeDictionary?

1. One who is known for achieving excellent results in a profession or field, such as business or politics.
2. An influential employee who creates a great deal of business or revenue for his or her firm

Comment: Looper deals with time travel, but this question doesn't. Removing TT tag.

Comment: Not an answer, just a piece of trivia: in the Italian dubbing the villain's name is rendered as “Sciamano” (i.e., “Shaman”), perhaps because any way of translating “Rainmaker” into Italian has too many syllables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Neither. It has to do with Cid's later use of his telekinetic power to destroy his enemies by exploding them from within. In this particular case the name is directly related to the effect of "making it rain" blood.**

[image: Cid first use of his telekinetic power to destroy a threat to his family.]

*Cid first use of his telekinetic power to destroy a threat to his family by "making it rain" blood.*

Comment: *"Cid **first** use of his telekinetic power to destroy a **threat to his family**"* +1, though I thought it was implied that 1) He did much the same to Sarah's sister prior to that.  So while that might have been the first demonstration for the audience, it was not his first time. 2) Sarah rushing to grab Joe and eject both of them from the building before the crescendo of Cid's actions indicates her fear for the safety of not just for the attacker, but also that of anybody else in the vicinity.  She seems confident he can gain control of the power, while knowing he has not yet achieved it...

Comment: .. I thought the actions of Cid were better described as *"Throwing a tantrum/Spitting the dummy when your TK level on a scale of 1-10 is ..42"*

Answer (score 0):

I assumed it had some strange relation to the *Rainmaker* robot that watered their fields at the introduction of Sara and Sid.